# continuous function on intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined on the interval $[0,2a]$
and $f(0) = f(2a)$.
Prove that there exists a point $\xi$ $\epsilon [0,a]$ such that
$f(\xi) = f(\xi+ a)$.

How do I start proving this? I'd like a hint to help me get started. Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x)=f(x+a)-f(x)$. Then $F(x)$ clearly is continuous on $[0,a]$.

Note that $F(a)\cdot F(0)=(f(2a)-f(a))\cdot(f(a)-f(0))=-(f(a)-f(0))^2\le 0$. So by the Root
Existing Theorem (as $F(x)$ is continuouson $[0,a]$ ), there exists $\xi \in [0,a]$ satisfies that $F(\xi)=0$, i.e., $f(\xi)=f(a+\xi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Consider $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+a)$
2. Discuss the value of $g$ at $x=0$ and $x=a$. (If $g(0)=0$, so..? If $g(a)=0$, so..?)
3. If $g(0)\neq 0, g(a)\neq 0$, can you use intermediate value theorem to find $\xi\in(0,a)$?